# Using a function relating two different dataframes with if condition - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, apply

> Hi there! I've got two different dataframes and I tried to use a
> function using these two dataframes to get the result of Points from
> DF1 over DF2 but if there is no points from a person in another
> dataframe it will divide by 1.
>
> I tried to use apply function but in't able to relate two
> dataframes in the same function.
>
> DF1

```
        Person      Points
    0   Person_1        25
    1   Person_2        20
    2   Person_3        14
    3   Person_4        23
    4   Person_5        40
```

> DF2

```
    Person      Points
0   Person_1        10
1   Person_2        40
2   Person_3         2
```

> Expected output:

DF_TOTAL

```
    Person      Points
0   Person_1       2.5
1   Person_2       0.5
2   Person_3         7
3   Person_4        23
4   Person_5        40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Person` column as the indices of both DataFrames, so the division is done by aligning/ matching the `Person` values (regardless of the order of the rows). Then fill the NaN values (the extra rows of `df1`) with the appropriate values.

```
df_total = (
    df1.set_index('Person')
       .div(df2.set_index('Person'))
       .fillna(df1.set_index('Person'))
       .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df_total 

     Person  Points
0  Person_1     2.5
1  Person_2     0.5
2  Person_3     7.0
3  Person_4    23.0
4  Person_5    40.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df2.reindex(df1.index) #reindex to have df2 same lenght than df1
df2 = df2.fillna(1) #fill NaN values with 1
df1['Points'] = df1['Points'] / df2['Points'] #then divide
df1
```

| index | Person | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Person_1 | 2.5 |
| 1 | Person_2 | 0.5 |
| 2 | Person_3 | 7.0 |
| 3 | Person_4 | 23.0 |
| 4 | Person_5 | 40.0 |

Comment: Beware that your solution assumes that the `Person` column values of `df1` are ordered relative to those of `df2` (as in OP's example). It only works because the division is done by aligning the indices.